# how to change from one Viewcontroller to UITabldeview controller?

Tags: iphone

i have coded in appdelegate.m as following to change from currentview to UItable viewcontroller?but i  am getting error,tab is a uitableview controller

```
    tab = [interviewViewController alloc];
[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[viewController.view addSubview:tab];
 [window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Comment: Please edit this question.  Are you talking about tabs or tables?

If tables, please explain whether you want to make this change happen dynamically during runtime, or you are simply modifying existing code to use a different paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

YOu never initialize tab, and you addit to viewController.  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

Do this:

```
tab = [[interviewViewController alloc] init];
[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:tab.vew];
```